# Powershell: Replace line that starts with string in text file by string and filename

Tags: powershell, replace, filenames

I want to replace a line in a text file that starts with the value STRING: .  I want to replace this line for each text file with STRING: followed by the filename without extension.

```
$src = "C:\Input"
Get-ChildItem $src -recurse -include *.mi | 
 Select -expand fullname |
  ForEach-Object {
            (Get-Content $_) -replace "STRING: .+","STRING: $($_.BaseName)" |
             Set-Content $_
            }
```

The script I have doesn't add the filename, it only replaces the line with STRING:

```
STRING: text to be replaced
```

changes into

```
STRING:
```

while it should be

```
STRING: filename
```

How can I include the filename in the replacement action?

Comment: When you expand fullname you get rid of all other properties, including basename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `Select -expand fullname` command so you have the full `FileInfo` object, which is output of `Get-ChildItem`, available through `$_` within the `ForEach-Object` script block:

```sh
$src = "C:\Input"
Get-ChildItem $src -file -recurse -include *.mi | 
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace "STRING: .+","STRING: $($_.BaseName)" |
            Set-Content $_.FullName
    }
```

I've also added `-file` switch to `Get-ChildItem` to be explicit about what we want it to return. There could be folders named like `*.mi`, which might not be an issue in your case, but in general using `-file` is safer.